# Using an array of objects to supply data to D3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around using data and constructing graphs. I'm building a configurable graph based on some user-defined information. This I can handle no problem. I've already got the code in place to set this up but I'm having trouble bringing it all together in a D3 chart.

Right now the relevant data is stored in an object array and all the information based on the variables is all good and shows what I wanted it to show.

For some reason I can't get the codepen to work but here is the code: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/rLWVpR

Some relevant code is also supplied below:

Current console output:

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 5632 more… ] test_page.html:141:3
Object { Institution: "For-profit", Currently owe debt; behind: 13.168724279835391, Currently owe debt; not behind: 21.39917695473251, Paid off: 63.78600823045267 } test_page.html:158:3
Object { Institution: "Nonprofit", Currently owe debt; behind: 2.548725637181409, Currently owe debt; not behind: 16.19190404797601, Paid off: 80.20989505247377 } test_page.html:159:3
Object { Institution: "Public", Currently owe debt; behind: 2.6679371129109097, Currently owe debt; not behind: 13.101476893758932, Paid off: 83.42067651262506 }
```

Image of test table output to HTML: http://i.imgur.com/DkVmlTX.png

My JS portion of code:

```
var minAge = 30,        // Minimum age for relevant data
    maxAge = 32;        // Maximum age for relevant data

var control = [],       // All rows in 'control' column
    SL1 = [],           // All rows in 'SL1' column
    SL6 = [],           // All rows in 'SL6' column
    ppage = [],         // All rows in 'ppage' column
    ppethm = [];        // All rows in 'ppethm' column

var c_priv = 0,         // Private institution
    c_pub = 0,          // Public institution
    c_privp = 0;        // Private for-profit institution

var priv_behind = 0,
    priv_ontime = 0,
    priv_paid = 0;

var pub_behind = 0,
    pub_ontime = 0,
    pub_paid = 0;

var privp_behind = 0,
    privp_ontime = 0,
    privp_paid = 0;

// Array supply graph data
var FOR_PROFIT = {};
var NONPROFIT = {};
var PUBLIC = {};
var relevantData = { FOR_PROFIT, NONPROFIT, PUBLIC };

/*
var sl1_owe = 0,
    sl1_dontOwe = 0;

var sl6_behind = 0,
    sl6_notBehind = 0;

var oweBehind = 0,
    oweOnTime = 0,
    paidOff = 0;
*/

d3.csv("shed.csv", function(data)
{
    data.map(function(d)
    {
        control.push(d.control);
        SL1.push(d.SL1);
        SL6.push(d.SL6);
        ppage.push(d.ppage);
        ppethm.push(d.ppethm);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < control.length; i++)
    {
        if (ppage[i] >= minAge && ppage[i] <= maxAge)
            continue;

        if (control[i] === "Public")
        {
            c_pub++;
            if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "Yes")
                pub_behind++;
            else if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "No")
                pub_ontime++;
            else if (SL1[i] === "No")
                pub_paid++;
        }
        else if (control[i] === "Private not-for-profit")
        {
            c_priv++;
            if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "Yes")
                priv_behind++;
            else if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "No")
                priv_ontime++;
            else if (SL1[i] === "No")
                priv_paid++;
        }
        else if (control[i] === "Private for-profit")
        {
            c_privp++;
            if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "Yes")
                privp_behind++;
            else if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "No")
                privp_ontime++;
            else if (SL1[i] === "No")
                privp_paid++;
        }


        /*
        if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "Yes")
            oweBehind++;
        else if (SL1[i] === "Yes" && SL6[i] === "No")
            oweOnTime++;
        else if (SL1[i] === "No")
            paidOff++; */


        /*
        if (SL1[i] === "Yes")
            sl1_owe++;
        else if (SL1[i] === "No")
            sl1_dontOwe++;

        if (SL6[i] === "Yes")
            sl6_behind++;
        else if (SL6[i] === "No")
            sl6_notBehind++; */
    }

    console.log(data);

    // Creates the test graph of data
    FOR_PROFIT["Institution"] = "For-profit";
    FOR_PROFIT["Currently owe debt; behind"] = ((privp_behind / c_privp) * 100);
    FOR_PROFIT["Currently owe debt; not behind"] = ((privp_ontime / c_privp) * 100);
    FOR_PROFIT["Paid off"] = ((privp_paid / c_privp) * 100);

    NONPROFIT["Institution"] = "Nonprofit";
    NONPROFIT["Currently owe debt; behind"] = ((priv_behind / c_priv) * 100);
    NONPROFIT["Currently owe debt; not behind"] = ((priv_ontime / c_priv) * 100);
    NONPROFIT["Paid off"] = ((priv_paid / c_priv) * 100);

    PUBLIC["Institution"] = "Public";
    PUBLIC["Currently owe debt; behind"] = ((pub_behind / c_pub) * 100);
    PUBLIC["Currently owe debt; not behind"] = ((pub_ontime / c_pub) * 100);
    PUBLIC["Paid off"] = ((pub_paid / c_pub) * 100);

    console.log(FOR_PROFIT);
    console.log(NONPROFIT);
    console.log(PUBLIC);

    $('#information').append("<table><tr><td>INST</td><td>OWE/BEHIND</td><td>OWE/ON TIME</td><td>PAID OFF</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>PUBLIC</td><td>"+((pub_behind / c_pub) * 100)+"</td><td>"+((pub_ontime / c_pub) * 100)+"</td><td>"+((pub_paid / c_pub) * 100)+"</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>PRIVATE</td><td>"+((priv_behind / c_priv) * 100)+"</td><td>"+((priv_ontime / c_priv) * 100)+"</td><td>"+((priv_paid / c_priv) * 100)+"</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>PRIVATE, PROFIT</td><td>"+((privp_behind / c_privp) * 100)+"</td><td>"+((privp_ontime / c_privp) * 100)+"</td><td>"+((privp_paid / c_privp) * 100)+"</td></tr>" +
        "</table>");

});
```

**Main Question:**

How do I use my array of objects to inject a d3 chart with data? I'm trying to make a stacked bar graph but I'm not really sure how to use that data to adjust stuff? Usually, for a data file like a CSV or JSON file you would use something like `d3.csv(myData.csv, function(data)` or something along those lines.

I'm just really at a loss and I feel like I need that bit of information to help it finally *click* for me.

*edit:* `relevantData` is what I'm trying to use for the data source. It outputs to the console as follows:

`Object { FOR_PROFIT: Object, NONPROFIT: Object, PUBLIC: Object }`

Comment: Check your console: *"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"*. Your csv never got loaded, hence `data` will be null, resulting in *"pen.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null"* when trying to call `data.map()`.

Comment: The data is fine. I get the data as proven by my output. The file is just not included here so it isn't loading it. My question was more asking how to use the array of objects I've constructed using that data to manage a D3 graph.